# Kinect + Depth + 3D Projection Mapping

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm looking for a **C# sample** project, tutorial, assembly to perform a simple image projection on a given 3D surface using kinect.

- Kinect provides a depth image that could be transform to 3D cloud of point
- I 'd like to Map an image to this point of cloud

I assume Image should be stretch by a transformations matrix to fit correctly ?

For example: projecting a checkerboard on a table

Comment: What API/SDK are you using?  Have you looked at the D3D examples provided in the Kinect for Windows SDK Toolkit?

Comment: Re-reading your question, it sounds like you want to project a 3D model in real space using the Kinect to project the objects.  Am I reading this wrong (as I think I am)?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I think he's looking to project an arbitrary 2D texture to the Kinect's 3D output.  Jean, that's not a trivial (simple SO script) task .  If you restrict your problem to flat surfaces you "might" be able to use feature detection to fit a textured plane to that surface.

Comment: Yes not really simple. The idea is to project a texture on a tee-shirt or a video on a curved wall, ... or projection mapping on a white box ...